# NoVNC: automatically start?

Tags: html, vnc

right now the user has to input the port, password, and click connect.

I'm wondering if its possible to just start showing the vnc immediately upon navigating to the url somehow?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using noVNC standalone (not embedded in some other application already), you can use the vnc_auto.html page which will automatically connect using the settings you specify in your URL (host, port, password, etc). However, vnc_auto.html does not provide any header/menu, etc. You can also get the full vnc.html UI page to autoconnect by specifying the autoconnect value in the URL parameters.

Examples

```
.../vnc_auto.html?host=HOST&port=PORT&password=PASSWORD
.../vnc.html?autoconnect=true&host=HOST&port=PORT&password=PASSWORD
```

If noVNC is embedded in another web application and you have control over it, then you can just call the `RFB.connect(host, port, password, path)` method when the page loads right after the `RFB` object is instantiated.